# Angular ng-repeat filter with predicate function not works as expected

Tags: angularjs, predicate, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my first time playing with AngularJS, and actually, I'm following the getting-started tutorial. It came to my mind that I would tweak the tutorial scripts to my understandings, by just adding a little that was not in the tutorial.

Basically, the **phone object** used in the tutorial was:

```
    {
        "age": 1, 
        "id": "motorola-xoom", 
        "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg", 
        "name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™", 
        "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation..."
    }
```

What I was trying to do was to add an auto populated select box for order the list:

```
    <select ng-model="orderProp">
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in phones[0]" value="{{key}}">
            {{labels[key]}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

and added a model **labels** to the controller:

```
    $scope.labels = {
        "name": "Phone name",
        "snippet": "Description",
        "age": "Newest",
    };
```

It was working as expected, except that I only wanted to filter the 3 properties above, so I think it would be easy to add a custom **predicated function** for filtering like this:

```
    $scope.isPhonePropFilterable = function (propName) {
        console.log('it DOES NOT get here!!!');
        return propName == 'name' || propName != 'snippet' || propName != 'age';
    };
```

and added this to the ng-repeat

```
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in phones[0] | filter:isPhonePropFilterable" value="{{key}}">
```

To my suprise, it was not as easy as I thought, my filter function was not called.

See it here: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BlqBc8?p=preview)

Did I do anything wrong?

---

**edited:** ng-repeat **filter** supports filtering **array** only, not object. The filter function returnes if **array** param is not an array...

Comment: Well, it was my fault. Ng-repeat filter supports **array** only, it did only mention array in the docs. And checking the filter function, it returned if array param is not an array....

Comment: Please make this comment an answer so that other people could notice this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it was my fault. Ng-repeat filter supports array only, it did only mention array in the docs. And checking the filter function, it returned if array param is not an array....